# Empty body with express and nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I am trying to insert a new record by express and node js using mongoose.

My config is my app.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import cors from 'cors';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();
// Conexión base de datos
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/marcosgarciatfg';
const options = {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true};

// Or using promises
mongoose.connect(uri, options).then(
  /** ready to use. The `mongoose.connect()` promise resolves to mongoose instance. */
  () => {
    console.log('Conectado a DB');
  },
  /** handle initial connection error */
  err => { 
    console.log(err);
  }
);

app.use('/api', require('./routes/nota.js'));

//Middleware
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));rs

// Rutas
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello Wooooorld!');
});
```

And this my nota.js on routes:

```
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

// importar el modelo nota
import Nota from '../models/nota';

// Agregar una nota
router.post('/nueva-nota', async(req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;  
  try {
    console.log('body: ' + body);
    const notaDB = await Nota.create(body);
    res.status(200).json(notaDB); 
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      mensaje: 'Ocurrio un error',
      error
    });
  }
});
```

This returns always `200:OK` on Postman with empty response and in the console log the body is always  undefined. What do I do wrong?

Comment: If body is undefined it means that request was empty. Have you checked what request you are receiving?

Comment: @Eggon when i print my req in log that is the result in the header: req: function header(name) {
  if (!name) {
    throw new TypeError('name argument is required to req.get');
  }

  if (typeof name !== 'string') {
    throw new TypeError('name must be a string to req.get');
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply express.json() middleware before using routes.

```
//Middleware
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/api', require('./routes/nota.js'));
```